# get top spending resources with azure api

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

I am a daily user of Azure and quite familiar with Logic Apps and other Azure tools.

I have 2 requirements,
1. To get an email everyday consisting list of top 25 resources which consumed the most credit amount on the previous day.
2. Get total spent amount of the previous day by all the resources in my subscription.

I achieved part 2 by setting up a budget and got daily spent from it through budgets API.

I want to achieve the same with part 1 of my requirement using any API provided by azure.

Please help or drop any questions. I'll be happy to explain.a

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `Usage Details` API, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usagedetails/list?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365)

Its `List` operation allow you to get the usage details where you can filter by date (`startDate` and `endDate` in headers). There is a `$top` parameters to limit the number of results, but it looks like they are not ordered by amount so you may have to do you own sort to limit to the 25 highest costs

Comment: I'm already using the Usage Details Api call.`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{My Subscription ID}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2019-10-01`.
I'm getting 1000 results which I found out was because it list all resources and its 'sub-resources' and I think 1k is the limit of the JSON array output. If we look into examples about $filter on the [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usagedetails/list) you shared, those contains spaces which is invalid as URLs are not supposed to have spaces. I tried %20 and '+' instead but failed.

Comment: You are getting 1000 results in 1 call or using pagination?

Comment: 1000 in 1 call. Actually, I'm using HTTP action of Logic App which is similar to Postman in some ways.

Comment: So you should maybe implement the pagination to get all the results (using « nextLink » in reply)

Comment: Pagination totally works. I set the value to 5000 and same amount of results were shown. Is there any way I can just get the unique values from JSON array and parse them to get the spent amount. I'm currently trying to make a node JS function for that.